# Flutter AnimatedList 2 columns

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to switch from normal lists to animated lists for better user experience.

I'm currently using Gridview

```
GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: List.generate(
            myList.length,
            (index) {
```

How can I achieve the same result with AnimatedList (displaying the list with 2 columns)?

This is what I have, but I would like it to have some animations when adding or updating content.

[image]